# kotlin annotation method in runtime

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations

I would like to know how to modify the parameters passed to a method using annotations in kotlin

for example

```
@Add
fun method(n: Int, m: Int) -> "what I want" method(n, m + n)
```

I have this processor so far but I don't know how to finish the job, does anyone have an idea?

```
@AutoService(Processor::class)
class ConstantProcess : AbstractProcessor() {

    override fun getSupportedSourceVersion(): SourceVersion {
        return SourceVersion.latestSupported()
    }

    override fun getSupportedAnnotationTypes(): MutableSet<String> {
        return mutableSetOf(
            Constant::class.java.name
        )
    }

    override fun process(annotations: MutableSet<out TypeElement>?, roundEnv: RoundEnvironment?): Boolean {

        if (roundEnv == null) {
            processingEnv.noteMessage { "RoundEnvironment is NULL hence skip the process" }
            return false
        }
        if (annotations == null || annotations.isEmpty()) {
            processingEnv.noteMessage { "TypeElement is NULL or empty hence skip the process" }
            return false
        }

        val elements = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Constant::class.java)

        // ?????????

        return true
    }

    fun ProcessingEnvironment.noteMessage(msg: () -> String) = this.messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, msg())
}
```

Comment: Annotation processors does not allow you to modify existing classes, only create new ones.

Comment: can I add an additional behavior before executing the function at runtime?

Comment: No, you can't. You can generate additional function/extension that would call the original function. To modify existing `method()` you would need to implement a compiler plugin and/or use some library for bytecode manipulation.